# Pyramid traversal HTTP PUT to URI that doesn't exist

Tags: python, pyramid, traversal

So I have a pyramid traversal app and I'd like to be able to PUT to URIs that don't exist. Is there a way to do this in the view config?

So for example I have this

```
@view_defaults(context=models.Groups, renderer='json')
@view_config(request_method='GET')
class GroupsView(object):

    def __call__(self):
        ''' This URI corresponds to GET /groups '''
        pass

    @view_config(request_method='PUT')
    def put(self):
        ''' This URI should correspond to PUT /groups/doesnotexist '''
        pass
```

Of course the put doesn't work. The context throws a keyerror on `doesnotexist`, but how do I get the traverser to match a view in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a separate class for `Group` objects with a `Group` context and an `UndefinedGroup` context. Most views work on `Group`, but you could have a special method responding to PUT requests for `UndefinedGroup` objects. Note that `UndefinedGroup` should not subclass `Group`.

```
@view_defaults(context=Group, renderer='json')
class GroupView(object):
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request

    @view_config(request_method='GET')
    def get(self):
        # return information about the group

    @view_config(context=UndefinedGroup, request_method='PUT')
    def put_new(self):
        # create a Group from the UndefinedGroup

    @view_config(request_method='PUT')
    def put_overwrite(self):
        # overwrite the old group with a new one
```

Your traversal tree would then be responsible for creating an `UndefinedGroup` object if it cannot find a `Group`.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I was hoping to not have to define an extra class.

Comment: You could avoid defining the extra class, but then your GET/POST/etc methods will have to account for both states of the `Group` object.. one which is real and one which is undefined. This way you just don't have views for an `UndefinedGroup` and those urls will 404.