# Pyramid traversal for PUT requests

Tags: rest, pyramid, traversal, restful-url

I am trying to create a Pyramid route for a `PUT` request in a **RESTful** API to create a new resource.  My application uses traversal, which works great for `GET` and `POST`:

```
config.add_route('myroute', '/resources/*traverse')
```

Since `PUT` should have the new resource name in the URL this obviously doesn't work with `PUT` since there is an unknown resource at the end so the traversal fails.  I tried to create a new route for `PUT` using a hybrid URL dispatch and traversal approach:

```
config.add_route('myroute_put', '/resources/{path}/{new}', traverse='/{path}', request_method='PUT')
```

This works great if and only if there is only path segment to traverse.  The name of the new resource is available as `request.matchdict['new']`  If we are at the root level, with nothing to traverse, we can still get this to work by making an auxiliary route:

```
config.add_route('myroute_put_root', '/resources/{new}', reqeust_method='PUT')
```

However, that's not a real solution because `myroute_put` still doesn't match if there are more then one path segments that need to be traversed, such as for the URL: `/resources/path1/path2/new_resource`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Stack Overflow question: [Pyramid traversal HTTP PUT to a URI that doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739993/pyramid-traversal-http-put-to-uri-that-doesnt-exist) proposes a solution to create a different *NewResource* context type to represent new resources.  The `__getitem__()` method of the *Resource* class can then always return a *NewResource* if it can't find the requested child.  Then, a view configuration can be setup for the *NewResource* context and `PUT` request_method.

This almost works, except by always returning a *NewResource* when a child isn't found instead of raising `KeyError` it breaks the ability to use named views as URL subordinates.  For example the URL: `/resources/path1/path2/my_view` would mistakenly return a *NewResource* context for `my_view` instead of using that as a view_name if it exists.

The best workaround to this problem I found so far was to create a custom Pyramid Traversal algorithm that first uses the default traversal algorithm, but then if that fails it checks if the `request.method` is a `PUT`.  If so, then it returns a context of a *NewResource*, otherwise it returns the results of the traversal as-is.